# date comparison issue in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to compare date in sql server and have to select the lesser dates for the given date and I dont know where I am going wrong and not able to get the result.
Can anyone help me on this. Thanks

```
 select CONVERT(DATE,CreatedDate)  from Asset
   where CONVERT(DATE,CreatedDate) < CONVERT(DATE,'5/12/2013')
```

Comment: What data type is CreatedDate?

Comment: Why are you converting the dates?  Why not just compare them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible the date is being misinterpreted? (i.e. Month <-> Day))

I always use the unambiguous 'ISO8601' form `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
select CONVERT(DATE, CreatedDate)  
from Asset
where CONVERT(DATE, CreatedDate) < CONVERT(DATE,'2013-12-05')
```

What data type is column `CreatedDate`? Does it have a time portion?